# If empty variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the code below:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";

$results = $db->query($sql);

if (empty($results)) {
    echo 'Momenteel geen nieuws.';
}

foreach ($results as $row)
{
    echo '<h3>';
    echo $row['titel'].'<br>';
    echo '</h3>';
    echo $row['bericht'].'<br>';
    echo '<br><br><div style="float: left;"><small>Schrijver: '.$row['schrijver'].'</small></div>';
    echo '<div style="float: right; margin-bottom:-20px;"><a href="#">Lees meer...</a></div><br><br><hr>';

}

?>
```

This code will fetch information from the database. But if there is nothing in a table, it needs to say 'Momenteel geen nieuws.'.
It doesn't say that, and i don't understand why it doesn't...
If there is somebody who can help me out, it would be very nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not empty even with no results. You can try `count()` instead perhaps?

```
if (count($results) <1 ) {
    echo 'Momenteel geen nieuws.';
}
```

> A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value
>   equals FALSE.

http://www.php.net/empty

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";

$results = $db->query($sql);

if (count($results) < 1) {
    echo 'Momenteel geen nieuws.';
}else
{
    foreach ($results as $row)
    {
        echo '<h3>';
        echo $row['titel'].'<br>';
        echo '</h3>';
        echo $row['bericht'].'<br>';
        echo '<br><br><div style="float: left;"><small>Schrijver: '.$row['schrijver'].'</small></div>';
        echo '<div style="float: right; margin-bottom:-20px;"><a href="#">Lees meer...</a></div><br><br><hr>';

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";

$results = $db->query($sql);

if (!$results) {
    echo 'Momenteel geen nieuws.';
}//end if
else{
foreach ($results as $row){
    echo '<h3>';
    echo $row['titel'].'<br>';
    echo '</h3>';
    echo $row['bericht'].'<br>';
    echo '<br><br><div style="float: left;"><small>Schrijver: '.$row['schrijver'].'</small></div>';
    echo '<div style="float: right; margin-bottom:-20px;"><a href="#">Lees meer...</a></div><br><br><hr>';

}//end foreach
}//end if else
?>
```

Comment: oh i forgot to add $ to if condition please try now just tested working for me